# How do you remove a class on click of body AND button JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code that pops open a sidebar and adds a class to the main container which pushes it to the right creating a slide effect. Currently it closes the menu if you click anywhere inside the main container unless it's another link.

The button I use to trigger the function is #menu-btn" but when I press this button when the menu is already open, it seems the function plays again instead of removing the class from the main container which would close the sidebar.

So how do I make the sidebar close if the button is clicked when the sidebar is already open?

```
var SidebarMenuEffects = (function() {

function hasParentClass( e, classname ) {
    if(e === document) return false;
    if( classie.has( e, classname ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return e.parentNode && hasParentClass( e.parentNode, classname );
}

// http://coveroverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
function mobilecheck() {
    var check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
}

function init() {



    var container = document.getElementById( 'st-container' ),
        buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '#menu-btn' ) ),
        // event type (if mobile use touch events)
        eventtype = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click',
        resetMenu = function() {
            classie.remove( container, 'st-menu-open' );
        },
        bodyClickFn = function(evt) {
            if( !hasParentClass( evt.target, 'st-menu' ) ) {
                resetMenu();
                document.removeEventListener( eventtype, bodyClickFn );
            }
        };

    buttons.forEach( function( el, i ) {
        var effect = el.getAttribute( 'data-effect' );

        el.addEventListener( eventtype, function( ev ) {
            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();
            container.className = 'st-container'; // clear
            classie.add( container, effect );
            setTimeout( function() {
                classie.add( container, 'st-menu-open' );
            }, 25 );
            document.addEventListener( eventtype, bodyClickFn );
        });
    } );


}

init();

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my button had a higher z-index. When I lowered the z-indew, the :after was higher and wouldn't allow the button to be clicked until you click anywhere to close menu. Works.